# Single table relationship with two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

My database schema:

```
LIKE      PAGE    ARTICLE    
id        id      id
userid    name    text
```

My Question - How do I make a relationship between PAGE table and ARTICLE table with LIKE table?
Normally:

Like.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="likes")
 */
protected $pages;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="likes")
 */
protected $articles;
```

Page.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Like", mappedBy="pages")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="like_page")
 */
protected $likes;
```

Article.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Like", mappedBy="article")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="like_article")
 */
protected $likes;
```

But, ID column will be the same in both tables (page and article). Will not be realized.
What should I do?

Comment: It may be better to have the entities store an AddressID - or to implement separate columns for each referenced entity and a check constraint in the database that ensures strictly one of them is non-NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your vague question and schema right, what you actually want is:

```
likes (
  id,
  user_id,
  page_id,
  article_id
)
```

- likes have one user (author), page (source) and article (target)
- users, pages and articles have many likes

Comment: But if i use this way, page_id or article_id will be empty. So, a field (page_id or article_id) will be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what Denis said. You don't really need many to many relation in such schema. One-to-many relations should be enough.

Like.php:

```
/**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $page;

/**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $article;
```

Page.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Like", mappedBy="page")
 */
protected $likes;
```

Article.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Like", mappedBy="article")
 */
protected $likes;
```

Comment: If I use this way, a field (article_id or page_id) will be empty. Unnecessary field are stacked.

Comment: I think doctrine disallows having only one external ID field for two separate entities. You could achieve this in plain MySQL using globally unique IDs, but you should not really do it unless there is a reason to. 
The other option would be to have two entities for relations, PageLike and ArticleLike, but you should keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a Like.php entity.

Your "Like" is an actual User.php who have $likedPages (Many-to-Many Page) and likedArticles (Many-to-Many Article). => REVERSE SIDE

Then your Page.php have $likes (Many-to-Many User) and Article.php have $likes (Many-to-Many User). => OWNING SIDE with join tables (likes_page_user and likes_article_user)

Hope that helps!